# Catching two exceptions: String (when Int is expected) and when Int is out of parameters

Tags: java, exception, try-catch

I am extremely new to Java programming (and to programming in general). I have been searching google forever and have not been able to find an answer to my question.

I am trying to make my program only except the year of their car that is between the years 1940 and 2016. I also want the program to catch if the user enters a string instead of an int. After it throws the error message for either of these, I want to ask the user what year there car is again until they enter a proper year. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
public class CarPractice 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
        int year;

        try
        {
            System.out.println("Enter your cars year");
            year = keyboard.nextInt();
            if  (year < 1940 || year > 2016)
                throw new Exception("You have entered a year that is not within the parameters of this program. Please enter a year betwee 1940 and 2016.");
            System.out.println("The year of your car is: " + year +".");
        }                                        
        catch(InputMismatchException e)
        {
            System.out.println("\t** You have entered an invalid input. Please enter a number and then try again.");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }

    } 
}
```

Comment: Throwing an exception in this case is not the best solution. Try putting your code reading the user's input inside a loop until you get your desired input.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below program.

```
package com.java.test;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class CarPractice 
{
    private static final int YEAR_LOWER_LIMIT = 1940;
    private static final int YEAR_UPPER_LIMIT = 2016;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int year = 0;
        Scanner userInput = null;
        boolean isCorrectInput = false;
        try
        {
            while(!isCorrectInput)
            {
                isCorrectInput = true;
                System.out.println("Enter your cars year:");
                userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
                try
                {
                    year = Integer.parseInt(userInput.next());
                    if(year < YEAR_LOWER_LIMIT|| year > YEAR_UPPER_LIMIT)
                    {
                        System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect year. Year should be in between 1940 and 2016. Please enter a correct year:");
                        isCorrectInput = false;
                    }
                }
                catch(NumberFormatException nfe)
                {
                    System.out.println("You have entered an incorrect year. Please enter a correct year:");
                    isCorrectInput = false;
                }
            }
            System.out.println("Year is :"+year);
        }
        finally
        {
            if(userInput != null)
            {
                userInput.close();
            }
        }   
    }  
}
```

**Note:**

- Do not import the entire package when you are using a single class. This will be a compiler burden. (e.g. Instead of `import java.util.*;` , use import `java.util.Scanner;`)
- Do not hard code the values in your code. If it is a constant, declare it as constant and use. (e.g. instead of hard coding the value `1940`, declare it as some meaningful constant name (for example `YEAR_LOWER_LIMIT` for `1940`). In long-term, this practice will save your time and headache while working on big modules.

Comment: Awesome, I will give this a try. Thanks!